# If $x$ identical machines can make $x$ widgets in $x$ minutes, how many widgets can $y$ identical machines make in $y$ minutes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

#### [Question](https://gmatclub.com/forum/x-identical-machines-can-make-x-widgets-in-x-minutes-if-each-machine-238806.html#p1841691)

> 1. $x$ identical machines can make $x$  widgets in $x$  minutes.
> 2. If each machine works at the same constant rate, how many widgets can $y$ identical machines make in $y$ minutes, in terms of $x$ and $y$?

#### I marginally rewrite the [avouched solution](https://gmatclub.com/forum/x-identical-machines-can-make-x-widgets-in-x-minutes-if-each-machine-238806.html#p1841924).

> Number of Widgets is directly proportional to Number of machines and Time taken.
>
> So we can write it as $W∝T\times N \implies W=KTN,\text{ where} \tag{3}$
>   W= number of widgets, 
>   T= time taken,
>   N= number of machines,
>   K= Equation constant (Don't worry about this :wink:).
>
> From sentence #1, $x=K∗x∗x. \tag{4}$ Solve for K: $K=\dfrac{1}{x}$.
>
> $\color{red}{Wy}=K∗y∗y \tag{5}.$
>
> Substitute $K=\dfrac{1}{x}$: then $Wy=\dfrac{y^2}{x}$.

I accept that sentence 2  $\implies T=N=y$.

3. But from where did $\color{red}{Wy}$ stem, in $(5)$?
4. Our goal is to calculate $W$. So why can we replace $W$ in $(3)$ with $\color{red}{Wy}$? The solution didn't, and it would've been wrong to, replace $W$ with $Wx$ in $(4)$.

Comment: Are symbols lost in translation? E.g., your final expression of $y^2 x$ should certainly be $y^2 / x$. Perhaps the original intention was to write $W_y$ with a subscript.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Yes. Your first sentence is correct. I corrected my post. Last sentence: Ah! Now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Migrating comment to ensure the post is marked as answered.]

The questionable component appears to be a transcription error; specifically, the $Wy$ is likely a mis-rendering of $W_y$ (where $y$ as a subscript did not paste over). So: It should not be read as the product of $W$ and $y$, but rather as a separate quantity where it would not make sense to reuse $W$ (which, in hindsight, might have been better represented as $W_x$ for consistency!).